# How to find d(A,B)?

Tags: metric-spaces

Let A is the rectangular hyperbola xy=1 and B is the union of axes xy=0.find d(A,B).

Now if A and B be two non-empty subset of a metric space X then d(A,B)=inf{d(a,b): a $\in$ A and b $\in$ B}.
Honestly I didn't understand this question and have no idea how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x>0$, $(x,\frac{1}{x})$ is in $A$. It is at distance $\frac{1}{x}$ of $B$. So, what is the infimum of such distances ?